# Removing null values from a list in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to remove null values from the below list, but unable to do so. Please help.

```
>>> xx
[[], [], [], [], [], [], ['5'], [], [], [], [], []]

>>> type(xx)
<type 'list'>
```

Comment: What is the question? What is the point of showing the results of type and dir?

Comment: So where are you trying your removal of null values?

Comment: Sorry @DanielRoseman, that accidentally came up. Have removed it.

Comment: @AnandSKumar, i have tried this method while True:
 try:
  xx.remove("")
 except ValueError:
  break

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create list without unwanted values (without empty lists).

List comprehension

```
xx = [el for el in xx if el]
```

With `filter()` and `lambda`:

```
xx = filter(lambda x: x, xx)
```

Comment: `xx = filter(bool, xx)` is even simpler.

Comment: Thank you. This actually works, but can you please explain what it's actually doing. I know it is slicing but still a simple explanation will be helpful

Comment: @fear_matrix it is just list comprehension with condition

Comment: @ojii Just be careful. bool(0) is False but 0 is not None. If your only aim is to filter out None, don't cut corners.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below code.

```
xx = [[], [], [], [], [], [], ['5'], [], [], [], [], []]
yy = []
def remove_if_null(xx):
   for i in xx:
       if i:
           yy.append(i)

remove_if_null(xx)

xx = yy
print xx
print yy
```

Comment: That's not a great solution... user3990145's answer is the way to go.